# Why I cannot use model<T>(at indexPath: IndexPath) method of Reactive<UICollectionView> type?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I want to get the dataModel of UICollectionView at specific indexPath, I noticed that there is a method called `model<T>(at indexPath: IndexPath)`, and I think that's what I need, but the compiler complains about like this

[image]

I also noticed that RxSwift has provided other instance methods like `modelSelected<T>(_ modelType: T.Type)` and I can use it with no error like the picture, I think they are the same type(both are instance method), but I get different results, is there something I missed when using this method? I would be happy if somebody can give some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `model(at:)` method returns a generic type. You have not given the compiler enough information to infer the generic type and that has caused the compiler to assume you are trying to do something completely different. Also, remember that the call can throw. Do this instead:

```
let myThing: MyThing? = try? collectionView.rx.model(at: indexPath)
```

or you can do:

```
let myThing = try? collectionView.rx.model(at: indexPath) as MyThing
```

The `modelSelected(_:)` method works because the type of T is specified as a parameter so the compiler is able to figure it out.

Comment: It works now! I saw the two functions use the same generic parameters, but didn’t think about that the type inference process may be different, and also the compiler error message is a little unclear too, thank you so much!

Comment: The compiler error is crazy unclear! Anytime you see a method that only uses the generic parameter as a return type (not in any of the parameters) you will run into this problem.